# Canadian friend wants to come to USA but he's afraid he won't be admitted because he was arrested but later acquitted. Would this be a problem?

Tags: usa, canada, criminal-records

What the title says. My Canadian friend got arrested for assault and death threats, but was later acquitted of all charges in 2017. Would he have any issues entering the USA?

Answer (score 7):

An arrest, without actually being charged, does not make a person inadmissible to the US. From [Canadians Requiring Visas](https://ca.usembassy.gov/visas/do-i-need-a-visa/):

> Furthermore, Canadians who have been deported or removed from the United States, or Canadians with a criminal record, including for driving under the influence, must satisfy other [requirements](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/760/kw/arrests) to gain entry to the United States.

If your friend does not have a *criminal record* in Canada, then there is no problem with admissibility on that point.

Comment: "criminal record" is a little ambiguous, because an arrest record is arguably a criminal record, but the [statutory grounds of inadmissibility](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1182) would not be triggered by an arrest record alone.  I realize that the choice of phrase is not yours but the US government's, but it might be helpful to explain in a bit more detail.

Comment: @PrimeException how does that work when a police officer witnesses a crime?  I don't suppose they have to call the prosecutor before detaining the perpetrator.

Comment: The first sentence is irrelevant to the situation described, because you can't be acquitted without previously being charged.

Comment: @PrimeException in the US, a police officer can arrest someone without formal charges having been filed, for example if the police officer witnesses the person committing a crime, or indeed if the officer has any other probable cause to believe that the person committed a crime.  That's still an arrest and will generally show on the person's arrest record.

Comment: @PrimeException I'm not spamming the question, I'm challenging your extremely unorthodox definition of "charge" and/or "arrest."  If you can point to a source that supports those definitions, I'll stop.

Comment: @phoog https://thelawdictionary.org/charge-v/  https://thelawdictionary.org/arrest/  I'll just leave this as is.  In your world, an officer arrests someone without making a sworn affidavit charging the person and when that person asks "Arrested on what charges?" The officer responds "You're not being charged and you're not being detained." I understand why there are so many bad answers on this site now.